# Is the Epoch Rewards sysvar deprecated?

Tags: sysvar

The [sysvar documentation](https://docs.solana.com/developing/runtime-facilities/sysvars#epochrewards) gives the address of the Epoch Rewards account as `SysvarEpochRewards1111111111111111111111111`

Using `getAccountInfo`, I'm getting `"value": null` for this address on testnet, devnet, mainnet-beta and a local test validator

The address is found in the `solana-labs/solana` source code so I think it's correct in the docs: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/4385ed11b1a955642944a6b11353c09b1fba9187/sdk/program/src/sysvar/epoch_rewards.rs#L135

It's not marked deprecated in `parse_sysvar` where some others are:
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/4385ed11b1a955642944a6b11353c09b1fba9187/account-decoder/src/parse_sysvar.rs#L107-L123

Should I just assume it's deprecated and no longer exists on any network?

Comment: what solana version is your rpc provider using? Is it v0.16 or older?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `EpochRewards` sysvar is not deprecated. It is actually rather new, having been added within the last year.

It will become live on v0.17, which is not on all networks yet.

If you look at the rust crates, you can see that [before v0.17](https://docs.rs/solana-program/1.16.27/solana_program/?search=epoch_rewards) the sysvar did not exist, and [after v0.17](https://docs.rs/solana-program/1.17.0/solana_program/?search=epoch_rewards) it does.

Here is the current Solana Lab's client's [source code](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/98a28735174c47e4849805d6432710dd78077da4/sdk/program/src/sysvar/epoch_rewards.rs#L135-L139) that has the SysVar available.

###### About the sysvar returning null:

Per the docs, this seems to be expected.

> When all rewards have been distributed, the sysvar is deleted. Unlike other sysvars, which almost always exist on-chain, EpochRewards sysvar only exists during the reward period

So when there are no pending rewards that need to be distributed, the sysvar will error (and I guess the RPC returns `null` for that vice an actual error?)

This sysvar should only return an actual value when there are pending rewards that are yet to be distributed

Comment: Awesome, the exact opposite of my guess! :D My local validator is on 1.17.15 and doesn't return anything for `SysvarEpochRewards1111111111111111111111111`. Do you know if there's a way I can convince a local validator to include it? For context I'm adding the sysvar accounts to web3js so being able to validate against a real response is really useful!

Comment: How are you trying to access the data?

Comment: I did some more research, and updated my answer about why the `null` response is expected most of the time